# Capistrano many failed status on linked_files and linked_dirs what do they mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

OK so all is working perfectly well as far as I can see, but I do see a lot of "failed" status on most of the linked_files and linked_dirs tasks and I am wondering if they deserve any attention. Here are a few examples:

```
DEBUG [423a17e1] Running [ -L /home/caluebat/www/ravenfort/releases/20160312213815/tmp/pids ] on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [423a17e1] Command: [ -L /home/caluebat/www/ravenfort/releases/20160312213815/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG [423a17e1] Finished in 0.470 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
DEBUG [541d2f8a] Running [ -d /home/caluebat/www/ravenfort/releases/20160312213815/tmp/pids ] on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [541d2f8a] Command: [ -d /home/caluebat/www/ravenfort/releases/20160312213815/tmp/pids ]
DEBUG [541d2f8a] Finished in 0.476 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

I was unable to find any detail on the capistrano official docs and they send either here or the mailing list for questions.

I would appreciate any clarification on the above failures.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about it!

Whenever cap runs a command that returns a non-zero result, it prints the line in red and says "failed". This can be misleading, because it runs a lot of commands just to see what already exists. For instance `[ -d foo ]` means "Is there a directory named foo?" It's not actually a failure, it's just cap inspecting the target machine to find out what work it needs to do.

If cap hits a real error, it will quit early and you'll get a stack trace and/or actual error message.

Comment: + 1 from `man test`, `-L FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)`, `-d FILE exists and is a directory`, `[ -d foo ]` means _Is there a directory_, nothing about name.

Comment: Thank you! by the way I was unable to find docs for -L and -d are the bash options?

Comment: So this is a little ridiculous . . . there is a command called `test`. You can read about it with `man test`. But to save some typing, it is normal for `/bin/[` to be linked to `/bin/test`. So the command you are running is `[`! The square bracket is not part of the syntax of a bash `if` statement, it is the command!

Comment: Thank you @PaulAJungwirth awesome! and yes, ridiculous too! :)